# can't install wine ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

First, sorry because my bad English.
I try many ways to install wine on my laptop but have no luck

Here is my error log

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-clutter : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not installable or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I follow these steps "1)sudo apt-get install -f 2)sudo apt-get autoremove 3)sudo apt-get update 4)sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 5)sudo apt-get update 6)sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 //the dependencies error) 7)sudo apt-get update 8)sudo apt-get install wine //this step will take about 4-7 minutes"

Comment: Any one help?i have faced with this problem for 2days

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in debian. there it was tz-data and I fixed it by adding the point release repository to apt and then did `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. I don't know how this is exactly done in Ubuntu (didn't face the problem there) but [here is the link of the Debian page](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/errata.en.html)

Comment: I reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 so i don't know if it works.Anyway thank for your suggestion :D.